# Apache Spark: Write to multiple sheets in excel

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I need to write the datasets in different sheets of a single excel workbook. 
I was able to achieve the same using the `com.crealytics.spark.excel` library.

```
df3.write()
   .format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
   .option("dataAddress", "lines[#All]")
   .option("header", "true")
   .save("hdfs://${namenode}/" + outFile + ".xls");

fdf3.write()
    .format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
    .option("dataAddress","newlines[#All]")
    .option("header", "true")
    .mode(SaveMode.Append).save("${namenode}/" + outFile + ".xls");
```

This is working good with smaller data and written in 2 separate sheets in a single worksheet, but it fails for larger data (Around 1GB file). So I switched to the new library `org.zuinnote.spark.office.excel`

```
df3.coalesce(1).write()
               .format("org.zuinnote.spark.office.excel")
               .option("write.spark.defaultsheetname", "lines")
               .option("hadoopoffice.write.header.write", true)
               .save("hdfs://${namenode}/" + outFile + ".xls");

fdf3.coalesce(1).write()
               .format("org.zuinnote.spark.office.excel")
               .option("write.spark.defaultsheetname", "newlines")
               .option("hadoopoffice.write.header.write", true)
               .mode(SaveMode.Append)
               .save("hdfs://${namenode}/" + outFile + ".xls");
```

But this is creating 2 excel files, not 2 sheets in a single workbook. Is there any option available to write it as new sheet in the workbook?

Comment: can you look into this - https://github.com/zuinnote/hadoopoffice

Comment: This has no information of saving in multiple sheets